# Open a new popup window and post data to it

Tags: jquery, popup, http-post

I'm using jQuery to open a popup and I'd like to send it data using the post method when it opens. Can anyone help me, thanks in advance.

I am currently passing the data using the get method so the data is a part in url, but I don't want the data to be visible in the url.

```
function openWindow(){

    var name = $('#name').val();

    var url = 'popup_window.php?name='+name;
    window.open(
        url,
        'popUpWindow',
        'height=400,     \
         width=650,      \
         left=300,       \
         top=100,        \
         resizable=yes,  \
         scrollbars=yes, \
         toolbar=yes,    \
         menubar=no,     \
         location=no,    \
         directories=no, \
         status=yes');
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: I have added the code i am using,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780912/sending-post-data-without-form

Comment: That question is for getting a PHP variable to another script (the answers all recommend using sessions), not a form value.

Comment: thank you very much for replying, is there no way other than session?

Comment: My point is that the session answer doesn't work for your question. I'm working on an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is based on the answer in [How to open popup and populate it with data from parent window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740783/open-popup-and-poulate-it-with-data-from-parent-window?rq=1)

```
var newpage;
function openWindow() {
    $.post('popup_window.php', {name: $('#name').val()}, function(result) {
        newpage = result;
        window.open('Popup.html', 'popUpWindow','height=400, width=650, left=300, top=100, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=yes, menubar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=yes');
    });
}
```

Popup.html should contain:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
        document.write(window.opener.newpage);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I think you can reduce this to:
        window.open('javascript: document.write(window.opener.newpage);'....
and you will not need the Popup.html at all.

Comment: I am also having same problem, tried your method but problem is it first loads data then open window, which makes slow response, i want it first open window then load data, what should i do?

Comment: If the post response is a file download (csv)...is there a way to to that instead of just displaying the file contents in the new window?

Comment: @AS7K I don't think you can do that in the post response. Javascript can't download files by itself. It would have to be done by `Popup.html`, which can send `Content-Disposition: attachment` to start a download.